# Not able to preserve the formatting of spreadsheet document.

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I am using data from spreadsheet between dt tags in my html code.I have used different font colors,font sizes in my spreadsheet document but while using the data within html code all the text loses the color and font size also changes to standard.....Is there any way to retain the formatting in my html code?

Answer (score 0):

Tools like [tableizer](http://tableizer.journalistopia.com) will let you transfer a spreadsheet into a table in html. And then from there you can style it using css.

You can use [GoogleDocs(Sheets)](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/). It lets you download your spreadsheet as a web-page and it keeps all the formatting.

You can also save your spreadsheet as html in excel (Save as web page).